# Node | Require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Edit : Problem solved using webpack

For the needs of an API, I needed to import `MD5` and `moment`. I downloaded the packages using the basic `npm install` but when I try to import it on my `app.js` using the code below :

```
const md5 = require ('./node_modules/md5/md5.js');
const moment = require ('./node_modules/moment/moment.js');

function getTimeStamp () {
    return moment.utc ().format ('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
}
let timestamp = getTimeStamp ();

function generateSignature (devId, method, authKey, timestamp) {
    return md5 (`${devId}${method}${apiKey}${timestamp}`);
}
let signature = generateSignature (XXXX, "createsession", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", getTimeStamp ());
```

I get this message in the console :

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I used the same method for another program and it worked perfectly...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably seeing this error because require() does **not** exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript.
If you want to use require() in the browser, then you need to use something like [require.js](https://requirejs.org/)

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for
>   in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments,
>   like Rhino and Node.

*PS: I agree with [cptwonton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3478797/cptwonton). Please refer to the mentioned post for an in-depth solution with the various options available.*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const md5 = require ("md5");
const moment = require ("moment");
```

Answer (score 0):

`require` isn't supported in a browser because Node and ES6 have their different module systems. Are you trying to call `require` in a browser? In that case I suggest you to setup Babel. But if you use node, then try reistalling nodejs.