# How do I go about using variable from multiple files in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I want to get a variable from one .js file to another .js file. Right now I have
main.js

```
const balances = require('./balance');
console.log(balances.balanceBTC)
```

and I have
balance.js

```
const balanceBTC = () => {
  return arrayCleaned[0];
};
exports.balanceBTC = balanceBTC;
```

And I am getting the error

> const balances = require('./balance');
>
> ReferenceError: require is not defined

I am running this code via windows PowerShell and the node version is: v14.10.1

Comment: How are you running this code and what is your node version?

Comment: I am running this code via windows powershell and the node version is: v14.10.1

Comment: check for node and npm is everything installed properly. looks like it's not able to resolve the `require` because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS might be treating your code as an [ES Module](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system). And CommonJS variables like "require" [are not available in ES modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_module_exports_filename_dirname). Try one of the below:

- As mentioned
  [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33741#issuecomment-639463213),
  declare `require` before using it.

  ```
    import { createRequire } from 'module';
    const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

    const balances = require('./balance');
    [...]
  ```
- If you have `"type" : "module"` in your package.json, remove it

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the problem is coming from the environment where you are running your code.
Check the following links and you'lle find the answser:

[Node | Require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427002/node-require-is-not-defined)

https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2020/05/require-is-not-defined.html

[Require is not defined nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343751/require-is-not-defined-nodejs)

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33741

Comment: None of these worked for me. I downloaded commonJS and requireJS and it still is giving me the same error.

Comment: Thank you very much, i had the exact same problem and one of the provided link has helped me!!